# Почему не работает FindAsync из EF Core в тесте с NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nunit, nsubstitute

Хочу сделать тесты для методов репозитория с помощью NUnit и NSubstitute. Всё подготовил и сделал первый тест:

```
public class Tests
{
    private List<BlogEntity> data = null!;
    private BlogsRepository repository = null!;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        data = new List<BlogEntity>
        {
            new() { Id = new Guid("daf362fc-4487-4338-8776-d5bca5bc2632"), Description = "A", Reviews = new List<ReviewEntity>() },
            new() { Id = new Guid("40503af9-7569-4015-879e-6f70d0088de1"), Description = "B", Reviews = new List<ReviewEntity>() },
            new() { Id = new Guid("3c7ffa34-a234-43dc-ab20-849b211190c2"), Description = "C", Reviews = new List<ReviewEntity>() },
        };
        
        var mockContext = Substitute.For<IApplicationContext>();
        var queryableData = data.AsQueryable();
        var set = Substitute.For<DbSet<BlogEntity>, IQueryable<BlogEntity>>();
        ((IQueryable<BlogEntity>)set).Provider.Returns(queryableData.Provider);
        ((IQueryable<BlogEntity>)set).Expression.Returns(queryableData.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<BlogEntity>)set).ElementType.Returns(queryableData.ElementType);
        ((IQueryable<BlogEntity>)set).GetEnumerator().Returns(queryableData.GetEnumerator());
        
        mockContext.Blogs.Returns(set);

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<BlogEntity, Blog>());
        var mapper = new Mapper(config);

        repository = new BlogsRepository(mockContext, mapper);
    }
    
    [Test]
    public async Task GetAsync_Test()
    {
        var model = await repository.GetAsync(data[0].Id);
        Assert.That(model?.Id, Is.EqualTo(data[0].Id));
    }
}
```

Но почему-то `await repository.GetAsync(data[0].Id);` возвращает null. Вот его реализация:

```
public async Task<Blog?> GetAsync(Guid id)
{
    var t = await context.Blogs.FindAsync(id);
    return mapper.Map<Blog>(t);
}
```

В этом методе работает маппер, но не работает `FindAsync`. Можете сказать как это можно поправить? Не совсем понимаю, почему не работает, я ведь добавил `mockContext.Blogs.Returns(set);`. Если в отладчике навести курсор на `mockContext.Blogs`, то там будут все значения из `data`.